# MVC Alternative for Ajax Oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Because Ajax is asynchronous it causes a logical division.  Here is my controller module.
All data requests to the server go through here and come back here.

```
function cType( type ) {
    var object_pipe = MType[ type ].pre();
    if ( object_pipe !== 'complete' ) {
        var string_pipe = JSON.stringify( object_pipe );
        cMachine( 'pipe=' + string_pipe , function( text ) { // cMachine is an ajax Call - here is the asynch call back
            MType[ type ].post( text ); 
        } );
    }
}
```

I create the module structure below so that the "space" split up by the async nature of ajax is now combined back into an object literal. `pre()` refers to before the ajax call and `post()` refers to after the ajax call.

```
/**
 **  MABAdder
 */
MType.MABAdder =
{
    pre : function() { // some logic and view elements called here
    },
    post : function( string_pipe ) { // some logic and view elements called here
    }
};
```

This structure works well except that now I call the view from the model which technically breaks the MVC pattern.

However the code is neat and organized and scales well.

Does this break any core tenets of robust code?

To me, It makes more sense to create a pattern that works with the async nature of ajax then to adhere to a strict MVC pattern.

Is this an acceptable framework seed?

Answer (score 0):

> this structure works well except that now I call the view from the model which technically breaks the MVC pattern.
>
> However the code is neat and organized and scales well.
>
> Does this break any core tenets of robust code?

If your Model objects require your View objects to function properly, Yes.

From your example above, Im unsure as to what you consider the Model and View?

The Model is a collection/domain of objects. They are completely self-contained, with complete data and behaviour.

The View is another domain of objects, again completely self-contained. An example of your View domain would be a web page, containing the objects of the class <button> <form> <table> <div> etc.

Being asynchronous should have no effect on MVC.